# Storyboard Segue using a table view and data from a plist

Tags: ios, uitableview, plist, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I have my data in a plist, which is a list of cities names alphabetized, it also contains a phone number which is to be pushed to the info view and displayed,when the user selects a row (city name) in the table view. I've gone from using a `NSMutableArray` to now a plist to hold my data, now my segue isn't working properly. The build succeeds in the simulator but throws an error when you click on a table cell. Any thoughts as to why this isn't working properly? I'm thinking its a variable either in my `cellForRowAtIndex`.. or in my `prepareForSegue` method.

```
#import "CityListTableViewController.h"

@interface CityListTableViewController () 

@end

@implementation CityListTableViewController

@synthesize cities, sections;

-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

//ensure this is the Segue which is leading to the info view
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowInfo"]) 
{
    //now setup info controller so it can function...
    //get the info instance
    InfoViewController *ivc = [segue destinationViewController];
    //get the selected row and city name from it
    NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    //inform the info view of the selected city
    int row = [path row];
    City *c = [cities objectAtIndex:row];
    [ivc setCurrentCity:[cities objectAtIndex:path.row]];
    ivc.currentCity = c;
}   

}


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {



self.cities = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]  pathForResource:@"cities" ofType:@"plist"]];
self.sections = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

BOOL found;

// Loop through the cities and create our keys
for (NSDictionary *city in self.cities)
{        
    NSString *c = [[city objectForKey:@"city"] substringToIndex:1];

    found = NO;

    for (NSString *str in [self.sections allKeys])
    {
        if ([str isEqualToString:c])
        {
            found = YES;
        }
    }

    if (!found)
    {     
        [self.sections setValue:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] forKey:c];
    }
}

// Loop again and sort the cities into their respective keys
for (NSDictionary *city in self.cities)
{
    [[self.sections objectForKey:[[city objectForKey:@"city"] substringToIndex:1]]  addObject:city];
}    

// Sort each section array
for (NSString *key in [self.sections allKeys])
{
    [[self.sections objectForKey:key] sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"city" ascending:YES]]];
}    

[super viewDidLoad];
}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}



- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{
return [[self.sections allKeys] count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{    
return [[[self.sections allKeys]  sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:section];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
return [[self.sections valueForKey:[[[self.sections allKeys]    sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:section]] count];
}


- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{
return [[self.sections allKeys]   sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"DeptCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

NSDictionary *current = [[self.sections valueForKey:[[[self.sections allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


cell.textLabel.text = [current objectForKey:@"city"];    


return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}
@end
```

Comment: SIGABRT#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}

Comment: That's not an error, that's the top level code of the application where Xcode stops if something generates an uncaught exception.  To get the real error location, either set a breakpoint on Objective-C exceptions in the "Breakpoint inspector" or wrap the `UIApplicationMain` thing in a @try/@catch and print the `callStackSymbols` in the @catch.

Comment: more specifically......*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary city]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x68736c0'

Comment: Do you have some class with a property (or method) called `city`?  (The most obvious way to get that error would be to write code something like `myCity = myObject.city;` when `myObject` is actually a dictionary.)

Comment: Yes I do have a custom class called "City". I renamed a property in it. Now I get the same error with the new renamed property. So it seems you are right. My plist uses a dictionary so I get sections in my table view. How do you think this should all be corrected now to segue? Basically I had this working fine when I just had a NSMutable array in my tableview controller.m, but now that I am using a plist instead it isn't passing the data.

Comment: The fix, really, is just to check your logic wherever you read that property from a `City` object and make sure that's the real type of the object and that it's not a dictionary instead (either by inspecting the code or using the debugger...or you could use the @try/@catch thing.)

Comment: After some checking I determined that the error is actually within my infoViewController under viewDidLoad. It appears this code is wrong...- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
 
    //this sets the title bar to the currently selected city, & also displays the current phone number for the selected city.
    [self setTitle:[currentCity cityname]]; 
    [phoneNumberLabel setText:[currentCity phone]]; 
}
When I was working with just an array for my data it worked fine. Now that I use a plist it is not working. Any ideas how this should be set up now? or in what format?  thanks

Comment: @PhillipMills - I believe the correct nomenclature is "Breakpoint Navigator".  Thanks though, I completely forgot you could add a breakpoint on exceptions.